# Run IronRuby code in a sandbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ironruby

I have a web application that allows users to input a Ruby program that is to be executed using IronRuby and have it's results output to a web page.

This is the code that I use to create the IronRuby engine and run the code:

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();

var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString
                (sourceCodeSpecifiedByUser, SourceCodeKind.Statements);

source.ExecuteProgram();
```

There is a security issue with this, because any user can run Ruby code that performs unsafe tasks (for example, enumerates/modifies files).

I guess trying to blacklist strings like `File.open`, `Dir` is bound to fail, so I haven't even considered this possibility.

Is there a way to run the IronRuby engine with lower privileges in order to avoid security issues?

Comment: Look into Ruby's $SAFE feature. I don't know anything about using it inside IronRuby, though.

Comment: @hdgarrood That's a very good idea. I tested it in plain ruby and it works fine. Unfortunately, it's not supported in IronRuby. :(

Comment: oh noes :( i'm out of ideas then. if you do find a solution, please update this question -- I'd be interested to know